# List with anonymous type

Tags: asp.net, linq

Here is my code

```
var personalInfoQuery = from t in crnnsupContext.Tombstones.Include("ProvState")
                        join n in crnnsupContext.NursingSchools 
                                     on t.NursingSchool equals n.SchoolID
                        where t.RegNumber == _username
                        select new { t, n };
```

then i try to put the personalInfoQuery into a list like

```
List<> personalInfoResult = personalInfoQuery.ToList();
```

but how to represent a anonymous type in a list?

I need insert it into the cache
so `Cache.Insert("personalInfo", personalInfoQuery.ToList())`
then `Cache["personalInfo"] becomes an object, how can i read data from it?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your type needs to be used by more than one method (it needs to be created by one method and read by another), it's not appropriate to use an anonymous type. Just create a simple type:

```
public class TombstoneNursingSchool
{
    public Tombstone Tombstone { get; set; }
    public NursingSchool NursingSchool { get; set; }
}
```

create it like this:

```
var personalInfoQuery = from t in crnnsupContext.Tombstones.Include("ProvState")
                        join n in crnnsupContext.NursingSchools 
                                     on t.NursingSchool equals n.SchoolID
                        where t.RegNumber == _username
                        select new TombstoneNursingSchool {
                            Tombstone = t, 
                            NursingSchool = n 
                        };
```

make a list like this:

```
List<TombstoneNursingSchool> personalInfoResult = personalInfoQuery.ToList();
```

put it in the cache like this:

```
Cache.Insert("personalInfo", personalInfoQuery.ToList())
```

get it out from the cache and read it like this:

```
foreach(var tn in (List<TombstoneNursingSchool>)Cache["personalInfo"])
{
     // do something with tn.Tombstone and tn.NursingSchool
}
```

Anonymous types are handy within a single method, but they aren't appropriate for *every* situation. Don't be afraid to make a named type if you need one.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the `var`keyword is for.

So instead of:

```
List<> personalInfoResult = personalInfoQuery.ToList();
```

use this:

```
var personalInfoResult = personalInfoQuery.ToList();
```

The compiler will figure out the exact type by itself you don't need to specify anything. This is by no means unsafe it is still 100% typed even though you did not define a type.

Comment: but what should i put into the brackets List<> personalInfoResult = personalInfoQuery.ToList();

Comment: @pita, you can't put something in the brackets, this is why var keyword is used

Comment: @Adrian Iftode, what if i saved the this anonymous type list into the cache, and then get it which will be an object, how to read the data from it?

Comment: @pita this you cant do out of the box. If you need to store it in cache: Create a class for it! Anonymous types are meant as ad hoc solutions, when you only need a certain structure for a limited amount of time